# Shell script won't run correctly when called in a while loop

Tags: linux, shell, export, command-line-interface, essbase

the following shell script reads a file but returns an error when executing esscs.sh:
`Error: Could not find or load main class a`

```
cd /u01/oracle/essbase/products/Essbase/EssbaseServer/bin/cli/
while read application; do
        if [[ $application = "" || $application = "#"* ]]
        then
                continue
        else
                ./esscs.sh login -user usr -password xxx -essbaseurl https://bla/essbase
                ./esscs.sh lcmexport -application $application
        fi
done < /tmp/exportLCM_applications.txt
```

The following shell script works just fine:

```
cd /u01/oracle/essbase/products/Essbase/EssbaseServer/bin/cli/
./esscs.sh login -user usr -password xxx -essbaseurl https://bla/essbase
./esscs.sh lcmexport -application hardcodedapp
```

This is the content of esscs.sh which an Oracle command line utility for Essbase (cli):

```
#!/bin/sh

export ERR_MSG_JAVA_REQUIRED="Install JDK8 and set JAVA_HOME variable to JDK8 installed location"

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]
then
    echo
    echo $ERR_MSG_JAVA_REQUIRED
    echo
    exit 1
fi

export JAVA_VERSION=$("$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')

if [[ "$JAVA_VERSION" < "1.8" ]]
then
    echo
    echo You are using older java version $JAVA_VERSION
    echo $ERR_MSG_JAVA_REQUIRED
    echo
    exit 1
fi

export SCRIPT_DIRECTORY=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
cd "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY"

export CLI_HOME=.
export REST_CLI_HOME=$CLI_HOME/lib

export CLASSPATH=.:$REST_CLI_HOME/ess_rest_cli.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ess_es_server.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ess_japi.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ess_svp.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/commons-cli.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/commons-io.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jersey-client.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/javax.ws.rs-api.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jersey-common.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/hk2-utils.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/hk2-apijar:$REST_CLI_HOME/javax.inject.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/hk2-locator.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/hk2-api.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/javax-annotation-javax-annotation-api.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jackson-annotations.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jackson-core.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jackson-databind.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ojdl.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jersey-guava.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/cglib.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:$JAVA_HOME/db/lib/derby.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ojdbc8.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ess-platform-common.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/datasource-model.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/excel-core.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/lz4-java.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/avatica-core.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/calcite-core.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/calcite-linq4j.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/protobuf-java.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/janino.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/json-path.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/checker-qual.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/jts-core.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/commons-compiler.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/guava.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/failureaccess.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/slf4j-api.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/slf4j-nop.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/commons-lang3.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ons.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/oraclepki.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/orai18n.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/osdt_core.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/osdt_cert.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/simplefan.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/ucp.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/xdb6.jar:$REST_CLI_HOME/esscatalog-model.jar
```

Comment: The file you provide does not appear to make use of any arguments passed to it (eg. `login`, `lcmexport`, etc). Perhaps you have truncated it.

Comment: Can you please share the contents of `/tmp/exportLCM_applications.txt`? If it is not "hardcodedapp" (or whatever you are executing manually) then you are comparing apples to oranges and all bets are off. I recommend adding an `echo $application` at the top of the `else` clause to verify that it is what you are expecting. The error appears to be coming from Oracle and is not a shell error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by reading the documentation which says:

> To execute multiple CLI commands, add them to any shell script and
> execute it. In any script you run that contains CLI commands, Oracle
> recommends you include the following directive before the CLI login
> statement: For Windows: set ESSCLI_ID=%USERNAME%*%random% For Linux:
> export ESSCLI_ID=`whoami`*$PPID This helps store session information
> and prevent execution errors when multiple scripts are run
> concurrently.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/essbase/21/ugess/download-and-use-command-line-interface.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).